# how to take a very large hex string and format the output

Tags: c++

i have a very long hex string in a byte array and I would like to format the output of that byte array such that it shows 0x??,0x??. The reason for this because I have a key that I am making and I don't want to type out a 512bit key like that. Any native code that could help me do that would be appreciated.

basically, i have a rsa key generated in hex and was hoping to use that as a static byte array. But, i dont want to type it all out {0x??, 0x??} etc

thanks in advance! you guys are the best!

Comment: What code have you written so far to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each byte in the array:
`cout << "0x" << hex << unsigned(theByte) << ",";`  where `theByte` is the value (hopefully an `unsigned char`) that you want to print.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout.setf(ios::hex, ios::basefield);
cout << "0x" << val << endl;
```

or in printf format

```
printf("0x%x", val)
```